# How to access Docker's Host network from within a Linux container on Windows?

Tags: docker, networking, routes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been setting up an application that uses Apache Web Server, PHP and MySQL. I already have the container applications working, and the only thing that i did not put inside Docker is the MySQL server, that is hosted on another machine in the same network.

The thing is that i don't know how can i access the mysql server from within the container. When i try i get "no route to server" or something like that. Docker Network drivers like macvlan and host do not work on linux. So my question is how can i route the traffic from the container to my physical local network so i can access the mysql database?

(OBS.: all the questions i found regarding this issue were trying to resolve this in a linux OS. Im running docker on Windows, and setting up a linux container).

EDIT: I'm trying to connect to the database using it's IP address, so i think that DNS is no issue at this point. Also, i've tried a network tools container to test connectivity between docker container network (default, bridge driver) and my physical network, and had no success. I can only ping the default gateway of the docker container (which i assume is the docker host's ip for this container), but can't reach anything through that.

EDIT_2: Ok, so aparently there is something wrong with either my Work PC or the images i tested because i've just setup docker desktop on my home windows pc, and now networking from container to physical network simply works. I will try the image i've made and see if it works. Just for record, these are the images i tried (and the commands i used to run):

`docker run --network bridge --name nettest -d -it jonlabelle/network-tools`

`docker run --network bridge --name nettest -d -it praqma/network-multitool:latest` <- this one worked on my home pc

The app image i made i cannot share because enterprise :D

Comment: You should be able to configure the external host name `database.example.com` the exact some way you would without Docker, and access it using default network settings.  The one trick is that you do need a fully-qualified domain name, just `database` will be interpreted as a container name.

Comment: @DavidMaze I will try to edit my question regarding this particularity but i'm using the IP of the server to try and connect. One of my tests was running a network tools container and testing connectivity between the docker network and the network i host the database, to no success.